# Remote Desktop Connection only works with downloaded file

Tags: remote-desktop

when a user tries connecting to any remote computer using remote desktop connection, the following box appears. When the user tries to open the .rdp file on the computer, no issues. Very confusing

[Error box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfGEu.png)

Comment: I'm wondering if the shortcut is somehow bad and has some launch parameters added to it.  Does it occur if they run RDP directly from `%systemroot%/system32/mstsc.exe` ?

Comment: It does work if run directly from the exe just, doesn't work when trying to connect to a computer from our website list of available computers
@copy-run-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the users Default.rdp file is corrupt.
You can locate and delete from the root of the users My documents. (Where ever you have that mapped)